# Text editor to open network files?

Tags: windows, editor, text-editor, binaryfiles, large-files

Currently i am using Notepad++ for opening any text file in windows. but if u have multiple network file opened in the Noptepad++ and you switch to it , it got hanged for 10 to 20 sec.
Is this problem same in all editor?
please share your experience if any know any better one.

Answer (score 0):

Most text editors will check to see if the open files have been modified since you loaded them. Over a network this can take some time (depending on the network).

However it looks like np++ is doing this on the UI thread and causing it to hang. Not all editors do this, so you might want to try others.

It is worth raising an issue on the np++ site as it should be fixable.